# FileZilla always discard local file

Tags: filezilla

Every time I'm opening a file in FileZilla, which I've previously opened, FileZilla shows a dialog with options: to reopen local file, or discard local file the download and edit file anew. As I always redownload the remote file, I'm looking for a way to make FileZilla stop showing this dialog and always redownload the file

Comment: This is very much needed. I am clicking and clicking and clicking "Discard local file then download and edit file anew". Need to stop that.

Comment: You can try going to the web address and then hit Ctrl+S (I don't know the combination for Macs, but more than likely it is Command+S), and that will download the webpage, or if you are viewing something like a video or text file, will download it in the format you are viewing it in.